# cron jobs for let's encrypt ssl renewal with mongod on nginx

Tags: mongodb, ssl, nginx, cron, lets-encrypt

I've got a parse-server up and running on digital ocean following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).
When configuring mongo db for migration you execute this command:

```
sudo cat /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain_name/{fullchain1.pem,privkey1.pem} | sudo tee /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
```

After that the tutorial says:

> You will have to repeat the above command after renewing your Let's Encrypt certificate. If you configure auto-renewal of the Let's Encrypt certificate, remember to include this operation.

In order to do this I added a cronjob to my let's encrypt cronjobs like this:

```
30 2 * * 1 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
33 2 * * 1 cat /etc/letsencrypt/archive/DOMAIN/{fullchain1.pem,privkey1.pem} | tee /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
35 2 * * 1 /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

However after restarting the server on a monday, mongod wouldn't start because it couldn't find/read `/etc/ssl/mongo.pem`.

How do I set this up correctly? Do I need to chown/chmod the file in another cronjob?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into a problem with the script above. Unfortunately let's encrypt doens't override fullchain and privkey but adds new versions when certificate is due to renew:
`fullchain2.pem`
`privkey2.pem`

So I had to alter the script accordingly. I also put the renew and nginx part inside so we need only one cronjob:

```
#!/bin/bash

# stop nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx stop

# check for new cert
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log

# combine latest letsencrypt files for mongo

# find latest fullchain*.pem
newestFull=$(ls -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/fullchain*.pem | tail -n 1)
echo "$newestFull"

# find latest privkey*.pem
newestPriv=$(ls -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/privkey*.pem | tail -n 1)
echo "$newestPriv"

# combine to mongo.pem
cat {$newestFull,$newestPriv} | tee /etc/ssl/mongo.pem

# set rights for mongo.pem 
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/ssl/mongo.pem

# restart mongo
/sbin/restart mongod

# start nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Comment: this helped me with a similar issue; but I'm curious why are you using the /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ and not the /etc/letsencrypt/live/ which has shortcuts to the latest files?

Comment: Actually no reason other than ‍♂️ - will review it soon :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here is what I ended up with.
I wrote a little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# combine letsencrypt files for mongo
cat /etc/letsencrypt/archive/DOMAIN/{fullchain1.pem,privkey1.pem} | tee /etc/ssl/mongo.pem

# set rights for mongo.pem 
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
chown mongodb:mongodb /etc/ssl/mongo.pem

# restart mongo
/sbin/restart mongod
```

and fire it with a cron job:

```
30 2 * * 1 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
33 2 * * 1 cat /root/myScript
35 2 * * 1 /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Comment: If this is run with cron, will the cat command not send root an email containing contents of your private key? I wish mongod had a reload command. For anyone using SELinux, don't forget to use restorecon on the new file if necessary